# How to generate a 5-set venn plot with R like that?

Tags: r

I want to draw a venn diagram like that, do you have any idea for it? 
Here is the picture link:[venn](http://bs.baidu.com/imemmi-tiny/%2F20150923233509_oH0Th7IMQP_s.jpg?sign=MBOT-iwImKL1Q98ibe5rybNr9CGRah0aZXyM-KYoct9m1CAvb7F8HefTasG2ABfc%3D&time=1443023150)

Comment: Maybe `draw.quintuple.ven()` from : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/VennDiagram/VennDiagram.pdf (first link on google)

Comment: Please provide some part of your source code, what you already tried, where you search etc...

Comment: This [blog post](http://www.buildingwidgets.com/blog/2015/6/5/week-22-d3vennr) shows an example with the source code of an *interactive* quintuple Venn diagram using the [`d3vennr` package](https://github.com/timelyportfolio/d3vennR/).

Comment: Interesting one. Thanks ! I'm a big fan of @timelyportfolio

Answer (score 3):

Try `draw.quintuple.ven()` from package `VennDiagram`:

[image]

**From the documentation**

> The function defaults to placing the ellipses representing the areas 1
>   to 5 in a counterclockwise fashion. Refer to the example below to see
>   how the 31 partial areas are ordered. Arguments with length of 31
>   (label.col, cex, fontface, fontfamily) will follow the order in the
>   example

Comment: yeah, I can draw the figure you listed, but I want to know how could I draw the venn plot on customed shape.